# How to get Cookies in Nodejs/Hapijs

Tags: node.js, cookies, http-headers, hapi.js, httpcookie

I am new to NodeJs Development. I am using HapiJs framework. I have set cookie using following code:

```
        reply("hello").state('cookie_name', accessToken, {
          ttl: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // expires a year from today
          encoding: 'none',
          isSecure: false,
          isHttpOnly: false,
          clearInvalid: false,
          strictHeader: true
        });
```

the above code is working perfectly and I am able to see the cookie being set in browser with the name `cookie_name` along with an extra cookie named `io` (which I guess is automatically set by `socket.io` node module I am using)

but when I am trying to get that cookie using following code

```
request.headers.cookie
```

It only shows one cookie (i.e `io`). its not showing me up the cookie with the name `cookie_name`.
So, can anyone tell me what is the mistake am I making here. Am I passing incorrect values in `options` while setting cookie or do I need to retrive cookies using some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our Hapi application, we're using the [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) plugin.

There is an [example application here](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2-cookie-example) that shows its use quite well.

Comment: what is `password-should-be-32-characters` here and is it necessary to be of 32 characters. Also is `sid-example` the name of cookie?

Comment: @DimpalSingh, for the password, they're just suggesting using one that's 32 characters *or longer* for security reasons.

Comment: Read the documentation at the top; don't just skip down to the code examples. It explains: "The 'cookie' scheme takes the following options:

"cookie - the cookie name. Defaults to 'sid'."...

Comment: Thanks, Finally it worked. But I needed to update hapi version to 17.0.1. Only then it worked. Thanks a ton mate.